# How to prove $\vdash_{HPC^*}A_3$?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I've been looking at some old homework logic questions and faced a question that I couldn't figure out what is the proof for it.

***Question:*** Let $HPC^*$ be a new proof system such that it has axioms 1,2 and the same inference rule as the Hilbert system, Also, we add to it a new Axiom $A_*$: $$(\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha)\rightarrow ((\neg \beta \rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow\beta)$$ ***Prove:*** $\vdash_{HPC^*}A_3$.

I know we must build a proof but I really tried hard and couldn't figure out how to make a sequence and get $A_3$ at the end of it.

The Hilbert system I'm using have the Axioms:

$$1.\ A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow A)\\2.\ (A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow ((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))\\3.\ (\neg B\rightarrow \neg A)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow B)$$

And the inference rule:
$$\frac{A,A\rightarrow B}{B}$$

So Axiom 3 of the Hilbert system is replaced with the one I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check that the proof of the deduction theorem goes through (as written!) in $HPC^*$.

Now assume $(\lnot B\to \lnot A)$ and assume $A$. As an instance of 1, $A\to (\lnot B\to A)$. By MP, $\lnot B\to A$. By the new axiom and MP twice, $B$. Now apply the deduction theorem twice to conclude.

Comment: So what you're saying is that using the deduction theorem I can simplify the expression I need to prove by doing these steps: 1. $(\neg B \rightarrow \neg A) \vdash_{HPC^*} (A \rightarrow B)$. And, 2. $(\neg B \rightarrow \neg A), A \vdash_{HPC^*} B$? If so, why do I need to use the deduction theorem twice again at the end?

Comment: If you can check the proof I added and tell me whether it's true so I can confirm your answer and also if you want I can send the proof I wrote so you can add it to your answer would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I proved it like this thanks to Alex Kruckman's guide:

According to deduction theorem proving $\vdash_{HPC^*}A_3$ considers proving $(\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha ) \vdash_{HPC^*} (\alpha \rightarrow \beta )$ which also considers proving $(\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha ),\alpha \vdash_{HPC^*} \beta )$. Proof:

1. $(\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha)$ - Assumption.
2. $\alpha$ - Assumption.
3. $\alpha \rightarrow (\neg \beta \rightarrow \alpha)$ - Axiom 1.
4. $(\neg \beta \rightarrow \alpha)$ - MP(2,3).
5. $(\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha) \rightarrow ((\neg \beta \rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow \beta)$ - Axiom $A_*$.
6. $(\neg \beta \rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow \beta$ - MP(1,5).
7. $\beta$ - MP(4,6).

Comment: Yes, this is correct!